# Typescript issue in Styled component Button ( React-Native )

Tags: typescript, react-native, styled-components

this code :

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

const Button = styled.Button`
  color: palevioletred;
`;

interface Props {}
interface State {}
export default class App extends React.Component<Props, State> {
  render() {
    return <Button> Test btn</Button>;
  }
}
```

throws this error :

> 

No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Pick<Pick<ButtonProps & RefAttributes, "testID" | "accessibilityLabel" | "onPress" | "ref" | "title" | "color" | "key" | "disabled"> & Partial<...>, "testID" | ... 6 more ... | "disabled"> & { ...; } & { ...; } & { ...; }): ReactElement<...>', gave the following error.
Type '{ children: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<ButtonProps & RefAttributes, "testID" | "accessibilityLabel" | "onPress" | "ref" | "title" | "color" | "key" | "disabled"> & Partial<...>, "testID" | ... 6 more ... | "disabled">': onPress, title
Overload 2 of 2, '(props: StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof Button, DefaultTheme, {}, never>): ReactElement<StyledComponentPropsWithAs<typeof Button, DefaultTheme, {}, never>, string | ... 1 more ... | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)>', gave the following error.
Type '{ children: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<Pick<ButtonProps & RefAttributes, "testID" | "accessibilityLabel" | "onPress" | "ref" | "title" | "color" | "key" | "disabled"> & Partial<...>, "testID" | ... 6 more ...

> 

i HAVE installed  `@types/styled-components`
why this occurs?

Comment: Try `<Button title="Test Btn" />`, since the `Button`, since the button does not receive `string` child

Answer (score 0):

Every button needs to have title and onPress proprieties, those are mandatories.
Your color style need to be one of the Button proprieties too.

So your Button component should be like:

```
<Button 
  title="Test btn"
  onPress={testFunction}
  color="#DB7093"
/>
```